# What is the `COLOR` environment variable?

Tags: environment-variables

What is the history behind `$COLOR`, why is no one using it, **is it safe to use**, and what should it be used for.

1. Why is it `COLOR="1"` on my "Windows Subsystem for Linux v2 Debian VM"? I don't have any shell rc-scripts on my system, except some custom `alias`.
2. Why is [GitHub not using it](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_help_environment), but this mess instead: `NO_COLOR`, `CLICOLOR`, `CLICOLOR_FORCE`?

Any wise Unix gurus? Thank you in advance.

*I deleted the previous question, because it was force closed, and spammed with offtopic commentary*

Comment: As with [the previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/761144/what-is-the-color-environment-variable), OP has shown no effort to trace where this variable starts getting set, so voting to close as lacking details. (Also: lacks focus)

Comment: @Junaga please understand that you come here asking for expert advise. The expert advise was very clear: we can't know what sets this, you need to figure out what does. Your reaction was to ask the same again, and not address what you've been pointed at, instead erasing the traces of you being pointed at it. Nobody's harassing you, you're just being explained how to work your problem, and how to not work with this community. Up to you what you make of it! It's no news to you that deleting a question and asking it again is a no-go.

Comment: 1. Arch Linux, which is not used for production workloads, not even available in CI/CD runners to build software, is an hobbyist OS. "Expert" has greater distance to an Arch Linux user, than a Windows VM user.
2. I don't care what or who sets this environment variable, I am asking if it i _should_ use it in my own CLIs in the future! How is that not obvious to you!?
3. I don't have "any problem", that is why I phrased my question this way, asking about history, conventions, and best practises.
4. you dont have to answer! you have no idea? fine. move on!

Comment: fine by me, i will wait 5 years until all of you losers are off the platform, and some real experts (ex IBM, Google etc) arrive. then repost the question. go install arch LOL

Answer (score 1):

As you saw, there is no standardization on such field. There were some discussion (some also recently) to standardize one environment so that programs know if they should use colors or not, but such proposals cannot solve many problems, and it would just create new environment variable.

So, check every program to see how they handle colours. Good programs should check TERM and then ask capability of the terminal (using libraries), but also they should check if they are writing to a console or to a pipe/file. But then we have problems: sometime it is good to handle different colours if we send to a pipe, but sometime no. As example: we may want to pipe results of a program to `grep`, and possibly grep will colour the matched strings (but so forbidding the first program to write colours). On the other hand, with `diff` we may want to pipe to `less` and so we want diff to pipe colours, and less to display them. So a generic environment variable solution is not perfect.

Microsoft not being Unix-like had own way, and so some portable programs had a third way to solve the problem, so adding mess.

And also your question may give an additional problems: to have coloured prompts we may uses variables on your .bashrc scripts, and in past we *leaked* many environment variables (the rc files are sourced on actual environment, not executed on a new environment). So you may get a COLOR just to simplify the logic of colour handling on your terminal (depending on how you connect to it).

So it is a mess. In any case, one of the great policies of Debian (early days of Linux things were much messier then we can imagine) was not to requires any environment variable in order to run any programs. So just ignore that environment variable. Nothing is required.

So: you should check every program (their manual page), and each program should tell you if they uses COLOR, and how they interpret it. It is not standardized, and so we cannot really answer you. (Googling `site:manpages.debian.org "COLOR"` doesn't really help, because it will find too much).

Comment: I am pipeing ANSI into an tty2html library to enable quickly scouting of serverless hosting environments. https://aureus-firebase.web.app/server/about

Comment: I asked ChatGPT too about any clues for `COLOR` it had no answer. The variable does seem really intuitive, if we could ignore the history, do you think it would be cool to depend on it in my own CLIs, to document it for users?

Comment: I'm not sure. a tty2html make sense only if it enable colour, and the problem are on the left side of the pipe. I would use like `ls`: `--colour[=when]`. auto will do the correct thing most of the time, and with pipe one has option to force things. And yes, you can use `COLOR` to provide a *session* default.